# Grails deploy: no such warName for class: Tomcat

Tags: grails, deployment, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

When I try to deploy to a remote Tomcat server using `grails prod deploy tomcat` I get the error: [image]

Has anybody encountered that?

P.S. On the contrary, the command `mvn tomcat7:deploy` works.

Comment: deploy is a script from some plugin? I didn't find it in the grails docs.

Comment: @SérgioMichels it's a Gant script from the tomcat plugin.
http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat - section Remote Deployment

Comment: Can you edit the plugin script Tomcat.groovy, change warName to warCreator.warName and try again?

Comment: @SérgioMichels great, you pointed me in the right direction and I solved the problem by adding 'def warName = configureWarName()' to the file! I now get 'Connection refused' but at least it's something different :D

Comment: @Comac Nice! I think you should raise one issue in the plugin to get it fixed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was resolved by adding `def warName = configureWarName()` to **Tomcat.groovy**

```
...
switch (cmd) {
        case 'deploy':
            war()
            def warName = configureWarName()
            println "Deploying application $serverContextPath to Tomcat"
            deploy(war: warName, url: url, path: serverContextPath, username: user, password: pass)
            break
....
```